# Launching MainActivity as new intent breaks it's views onClicks that start new intents android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-memory

I want to know why Android fails to load my activities.

I have intents set up in a RecyclerView within the `MainActivity` that launch another activity (`Activity2`). Currently this is no problems when opening the app and clicking these items.

I have a widget that is also set up to open `Activity2`. It does so correctly without any problems to backstack navigation, except when the app was closed. In which case the widget just closed the app instead of the back button going from `Activity2` to `MainActivity`.

The manifest declares both activities as "SingleTop".

In order to fix this, I added code to the `onBackPressed()` method and bundle extra to know if widget or main started `Activity2`. Now code will start an intent for `MainActivity` if widget launched `Activity2` from an empty/closed app, but the onClicks for the items no longer function to launch `Activity2` in this case.

TLDR: Intent that starts `MainActivity` breaks intent launches back to activity that started `MainActivity`.

This is my code that ends the 2nd activity if widget started from dead activity.

```
        if(mDidWidgetStart && isTaskRoot()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isTaskRoot and widget started");
            Intent mainActIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerActivity.this, MainMediaActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainActIntent);
            finish();
}
```

In my manifest, both activities are declared with `android:launchMode:"singleTop"`.

My onclick is called within the RV item like such:

```
    if(...) {

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) v.getContext(),
                    holder.thumbnailView,
                    holder.thumbnailView.getTransitionName());

            VideoParcelable ytVideo = (VideoParcelable) 

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Intent launched", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent myIntent= new Intent(mContext, 
            MediaPlayerActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("video_object", video);

            MyIntent.putExtras(options.toBundle());
            mContext.startActivity(MyIntent);
            //logging to determine values are present
            Log.v(TAG, "mContext = " + mContext);
            Log.v(TAG, "v.getContext() = " + v.getContext());
            Log.v(TAG, "myIntent: " + myIntent);
}
```

I know the above code's if statement and mContext is correct because the `Toast` message appears when the item is clicked, but the intent is never started. The logs from a failed click return non null values.

**ADDED WIDGET UPDATE CODE REQUESTED IN A COMMENT**

```
private static RemoteViews getDefaultWidgetViews(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.video_widget);
    Intent launchMainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainMediaActivity.class);
    //set pending intent
    PendingIntent appPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchMainActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //sets actual click action on the widget layout view
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.video_widget_layout, appPendingIntent);
    //return created remote views
    return remoteViews;
}
```

**UPDATE:** After giving up and restarting project at a later time this bug is no longer showing itself. I've changed no code... Could this be caused by a gradle sync problem of some sort? It couldn't have been the emulator, as the same results happened on my handset.

*note to self, screen shot and capture every detail of any future weirdness such as this. Does anyone know if/where AS keeps old Logcat output from previous sessions or is it always cleared?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in logs?

Comment: No, but I did notice the memory addresses changed at the ends of the context logs from normal activity flow to the widget intent ones. Like the 6 letter/number combination, for instance "MainMediaActivity@3933e2b" then "MainMediaActivity@23b88ea".

Comment: Please show a code where you start an activity from a widget.